# Is there a quick way to determine precedence and associativity of operators?

Tags: perl, operator-precedence, associativity

I know about perlop. What I am looking for is a quick lookup like the GHCi `:info` command:

```
ghci> :info (+)
class (Eq a, Show a) => Num a where
    (+) :: a -> a -> a
    ...
    -- Defined in GHC.Num
infixl 6 +
```

where I learn `(+)` is left-associative and has a precedence level of 6 from the `infixl 6 +` line.

Comment: If you could turn your answer non perl-specific (requesting the same for any language) I would be glad.

Comment: Is `perldoc perlop | head -60` not quick enough?

Comment: i had a perlish solution in mind but that will do fine :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realize that it is not exactly what you ask for, but what about:

```
perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e "print $a+$b*$c**$d;"
```

it prints parentheses around the expressions according to precedence:

```
print(($a + ($b * ($c ** $d))));
```

And for things out of perl distibution, you can look on [perlopquick](https://github.com/fod/perlopquick) - the pod arranged very similar manner as you specified in your question.

Comment: That is interesting. Could you please explain what the comma does?

Comment: @mugen kenichi: `-M` loads the module (`O` in this case) and gives parameters following `=` to its import sub. It is basically equivalent to `use O qw(Deparse -p);` in your code. `O` loads specific compiler backend, in this case `B::Deparse`, `-p` being its parameter. See `perldoc B::Deparse` for full list of its options.

Comment: ah so -p is a parameter to Deparse not to perl. perlopquick is also a nice find for me.

Answer (score 1):

Any reasonable reference manual and electronic version or help facility for the language should include the operator precedence in a list either horizontal or vertical, starting with the first entry as the highest prcedence.